# Ok to GC.Collect

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing, garbage-collection

I know there are a lot of topics about this out there, and it's generally a bad idea, but this is a relatively specific case. The only thing I've been able to do to fix the issue besides GC.Collect, is "slow down" the app, or use fewer threads. I have reproduced a small portion of what my app actually does, so I can recreate the issue locally. The following code gets an $OutOfMemoryException very quickly. *Note i didn't include the part where it gets the byte[] i1, but it is pretty generic.

```
private static byte[] i1;
private static  IList<Guid> jobs;
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        jobs = new List<Guid>();
        StartThreads(5);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

 public static void StartThreads(int maxThreads)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            tcount ++;
            if (jobs.Count >= maxThreads) continue;
            ThreadStart ts = (ProcessImage);

            var workerThread = new Thread(ts) { IsBackground = true };
            workerThread.Start();
        }
    }

public static void ProcessImage()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        try
        {
            lock (jobs)
            {
                jobs.Add(guid);
            }

            var x = ByteArrayToImage(i1);
            var y = ByteArrayToImage(i1);
            OverlayImages(x, y);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (jobs)
            {
                jobs.Remove(guid);
            }
           // GC.Collect();
        }
    }


 private static void OverlayImages(Image ymcImage, Image kImage)
    {
        var attr = new ImageAttributes();
        attr.SetColorKey(Color.White, Color.White);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ymcImage);
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, ymcImage.Width, ymcImage.Height);
            var templateBmp = new Bitmap(kImage);
            g.DrawImage(templateBmp, destRect, 0, 0, kImage.Width, kImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);
        g.Dispose();
    }

  public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] image)
    { 
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image))
        {

           return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

If I bump the max number of threads lower than 5, I can see (by watching the process in the task manager) memory goes up, and about every 9 "ticks"(when the task manager updates. each about 1 second or so) it reclaims most of it. With 5 or higher, the memory seems to get to the fatal level(around 1.6G) before the first 9 "ticks" and crashes. At 4 threads I can see the memory build up to a little over 1G, and then come back to about 70M, and repeat. Fewer threads, the less it goes up in the time before collection. If I uncomment the GC.Collect, I can run 20 threads and the memory stays between 100 and 200 M.

I've also been playing around with various things in the ByteArrayToImage to try and not use so much memory, but I've had lo real success with this. This includes cloning the image and returning that outside the using and removing the using statement among other things

Also my app doesn't work this quickly and it's hard to tell exactly what's happening. I can't reproduce the heavy load in the full app in testing environments. but it will get the OutOfMemoryException once a day or so. It will get several in a row and recover on it's own, but several jobs are lost in the process. I don't know for sure that this will even fix my issue or not, but it's what I've come across in my testing. I guess I'm just wondering what others with a bit more expertise think about this, and if there is a better alternative here than invoking the GC on my own.

Comment: You should *absolutely* be using less threads.  Creating tons and tons of short lived threads doing very small amounts of work is a very bad idea.  You shouldn't be doing that.  Messing with the garbage collector isn't the solution to that problem.

Comment: Memory profiling may help you identify where the issue is at.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Your snippet is very misleading, that *templateBmp* will always crash your code with an OOM.  There is very, very little reason left in this day and age to have a program like this crash because too many threads create too many bitmap objects.  Remove the jitter forcing so the program can run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: switching to Any CPU or x64 is definitely helping out. Taking templateBmp and just using the kImage directly is helping too, though I don't know how that will affect the outcome of the image.